# Is it possible to take multiple sentences as commandline input?

Tags: bash

For various reasons, I have to take multiple strings ( strings may include multiple words ) as command-line input.Say,

```
./temp.sh "OS Lab" "Mad man" "Spiky Boii"
```

But I was never able to achieve said goal so to test everything else i wrote this.

```
while read -r line
do
    array=("${array[@]}" "$line")
done
```

Now that the above code met my requirements since it's not what was asked i have been trying to get similar functionality using this.

```
for i in $*
do  
    array=("${array[@]}" "$i")
done
```

But this code takes 6 array elements if i give the initial input. How do i just get

```
array[0]="OS Lab"
array[1]="Mad man"
array[2]="Spiky Boii"
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the `$*` to `$@` and quote it:

```
for i in "$@"
do  
  array+=("$i")
done
```

Alternatively you can simply do:

```
for i
do  
  array+=("$i")
done
```

Also note there is no need to include the rest of the array with each iteration.  You can use `+=` to add elements to an array rather than completely resetting it each time.

**However** if all you are doing is adding the parameters to an array you can simply do:

```
array=("$@")
```

No loop needed.

---

From the bash manual on [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> (`$*`) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

> (`$@`) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. In contexts where word splitting is performed, this expands each positional parameter to a separate word; if not within double quotes, these words are subject to word splitting. In contexts where word splitting is not performed, this expands to a single word with each positional parameter separated by a space. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, and word splitting is performed, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters, `"$@"` and `$@` expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

---

From the bash manual on [Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs):

> If ‘in words’ is not present, the for command executes the commands once for each positional parameter that is set, as if ‘in "$@"’ had been specified

---

From the bash manual on [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters):

> In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to a shell variable or array index (see Arrays), the ‘+=’ operator can be used to append to or add to the variable’s previous value.

Comment: Thank You so much. That worked perfectly.